# How to get lines of "type=b" in a legend

Tags: r, legend

Is there a way to get `type = "b"` as the line type in my legend?

I want my legend look the same as the points in the plot:

```
x  <-  c(1:3)
plot(x, x, type="b")
legend("bottomright", c("dinges"), cex=1.2, pch=c(21), lty=1, bty="n")
```

Comment: A quick search through the Googles seems to indicate that this is a popular request without a satisfying solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add `pt.bg = 'white'`. This whitens the background color of the point.

```
plot(x, x, type="b")
legend("bottomright", c("dinges"), cex=1.2, pch = 21,pt.bg = 'white', lty = 1, bty="n")
```

Comment: I am sory if the question was not clear, I intend to plot a line through the point in the legend that does not show below the point. the current script gives a continuous line through the point...

Comment: thanks! I think it is the closest to what I intended to do. The intended `type="b"` seems impossible.

Comment: @Elvis which system are you using?

Comment: I use linux. On an X11 device, this solution produces in the legend a line which touches the circle, while on the plot it is disconnected. I built myself a solution by modifying the function 'legend'.

Answer (score -1):

I am attempting the same task. Including `lty` and `pch` parameters in the `legend()` call gets the job done.